# Android convering JSONArray to List<class> with GSON

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

When i want to get list from our webservice that return this result as an `JSONArray`

```
[{
  "b_code": 1,
  "c_code": 4,
  "f_code": 5462,
  "f_date": "\/Date(1555270200000+0430)\/",
  "f_meghdar": 11,
  "k_code": 1,
  "k_count": 150,
  "k_pay": 1500,
  "kalanam": "",
  "o_anbar": "",
  "o_code": 1,
  "o_date": "\/Date(1555183800000+0430)\/",
  "o_rasmi": true,
  "u_code": 0
}, 
...
]
```

now when i convert this array to class as `List<Offers>` for example:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<List<Offers>>() {}.getType();
List<Offers> contactList = gson.fromJson(response.body().toString(), type);
```

i get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $[0]
```

`response.body()` output:

```
response.body() = {ArrayList@12995}  size = 4
 0 = {Offers@13020} 
 1 = {Offers@13021} 
 2 = {Offers@13022} 
 3 = {Offers@13023}
```

`Offers` class structure:

```
public class Offers{
    @SerializedName("b_code")
    private Long mBCode;

    @SerializedName("c_code")
    private Long mCCode;

    @SerializedName("f_code")
    private Long mFCode;

    @SerializedName("f_date")
    private String mFDate;

    @SerializedName("f_meghdar")
    private Long mFMeghdar;

    @SerializedName("k_code")
    private Long mKCode;

    @SerializedName("k_count")
    private Long mKCount;

    @SerializedName("k_pay")
    private Long mKPay;

    @SerializedName("kalanam")
    private String mKalanam;

    @SerializedName("o_anbar")
    private String mOAnbar;

    @SerializedName("o_code")
    private Long mOCode;

    @SerializedName("o_date")
    private String mODate;

    @SerializedName("o_rasmi")
    private Boolean mORasmi;

    @SerializedName("u_code")
    private Long mUCode;

    /*GETTERS AND SETTERS*/
}
```

Comment: can you pass your data model class here please ? The error is inside the object which you might have declared an Object of `WhateverTheType` but in fact this response (inside the array) doesn't have another object .

Comment: @StavroXhardha yes sure, my post updated

Comment: can you log this response.body().toString() , want to know if its a valid json string or not.

Comment: take a look at here https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-mapping-of-arrays-and-lists-of-objects

Comment: is this all you have ? I believe you should have  a class where you hold an Array of Offers and maybe some other fields.

Comment: @DolDurma Are you using `Retrofit` ?

Comment: @theapache64 yes i'm using Retrofit

Comment: @RaviRajput `[{"b_code":1,"c_code":4,"f_code":5462,"f_date":"/Date(1555270200000+0430)/","f_meghdar":11,"k_code":1,"k_count":150,"k_pay":1500,"kalanam":"xxxx","o_anbar":"xxx","o_code":1,"o_date":"/Date(1555183800000+0430)/","o_rasmi":true,"u_code":0},{"b_code":2,"c_code":7,"f_code":1503,"f_date":"/Date(1555270200000+0430)/","f_meghdar":2500,"k_code":2,"k_count":1200,"k_pay":150,"kalanam":"xxx","o_anbar":"xxx","o_code":3,"o_date":"/Date(1555183800000+0430)/","o_rasmi":true,"u_code":0}]`

Comment: @DolDurma replace toString() by string() at response.body().toString(). if response is HttpResponse

Comment: @RajasekaranM i don't understand me

Comment: replace `response.body().toString()` by `response.body().string()` because to toString() should not provide your response and it's just provide object id

Answer (score 0):

Use like below

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<List<Offers>>() {}.getType();
List<Offers> contactList = gson.fromJson(response.body().string(), type);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're using `Retrofit`, you don't have to use `gson` to parse `JSON`. When you're calling `response.body()`, retrofit automatically converts the `JSON` string to pojo element.

Currently, when you're doing `response.body().toString()`, it first converts the body to `List<Offer>`, and then calling `toString()` on the `List<Offers>` object.That's why you're getting

```
0 = {Offers@13020} 
 1 = {Offers@13021} 
 2 = {Offers@13022} 
 3 = {Offers@13023}
```

The problem must be in your API interface. You might have defined wrong return variable for the method.

For example.

If your root element is

```
[{
  "b_code": 1,
  "c_code": 4,
  "f_code": 5462,
  "f_date": "\/Date(1555270200000+0430)\/",
  "f_meghdar": 11,
  "k_code": 1,
  "k_count": 150,
  "k_pay": 1500,
  "kalanam": "",
  "o_anbar": "",
  "o_code": 1,
  "o_date": "\/Date(1555183800000+0430)\/",
  "o_rasmi": true,
  "u_code": 0
}, 
...
]
```

Then your API `interface` method should be something like this

```java
@GET("get_offers")
Call<**List<Offers>**> getOffers();
```

Comment: i use this structure of API interface